# ODBC connection in Java for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java

I have a question about connecting access database in java for windows 7 - 64 bit.

When I working on windows 7 64 bit there is a problem in connecting the database even when I added the database by using `C:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: what exception do you get? Also could you please show us the connection part coding?

Comment: Explain what the problem is instead of just saying "there is a problem".

Comment: without showing code you are not getting exact answers?